# What is the best mysql configuration for mysql instance with a lot of databases and lot of tables inside?

Tags: mysql, memory-management, innodb

I have a mysql database instance with more than 3000 database inside. Each database contains more than 200 tables. I have more than 100 gb of data in all these database at present. I am using windows server 2012R2 operating system with a 4GB of RAM. The RAM memory utilization of the server system was always showing very high. So I tried to restart the system and restart is not working. It is showing restarting for long time and not restarting. When i checked the logs I understood that there is a memory issue. I want to restart my mysql instance and continue. What is the best configuration for the mysql with above architecture? what i need to do to make this work with out failure in future?

```
[Warning] InnoDB: Difficult to find free blocks in the buffer pool (1486 search iterations)! 1486 failed attempts to flush a page! Consider increasing the buffer pool size. It is also possible that in your Unix version fsync is very slow, or completely frozen inside the OS kernel. Then upgrading to a newer version of your operating system may help. Look at the number of fsyncs in diagnostic info below. Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0. 26099 OS file reads, 1 OS file writes, 1 OS fsyncs. Starting InnoDB Monitor to print further diagnostics to the standard output.
```

Comment: Please don't cross-post.

Comment: This question is not about a specific code problem, so it doesn't meet Stack Overflow's [criteria for on-topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). The question belongs on dba.stackexchange.com.